# DLL testing in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, dll, automation, mtm

Hi guys i'm new both to this site and to testing and i'm having trouble finding solutions to this problem.

My current project produces a .DLL file as its build and im looking to use visual studio to automate testing on it every time a new build kicks off.
To run the program a .exe must be triggered in the same directory as the newly created .dll this isn't a problem and wouldn't need automating except i need to kick of 16 different variations of it using different config files and separate  machines on a physical network for each variation.

Is there anyway to do this using visual studio 2010 ultimate and MTM?
I have looked into generic testing but it runs the exe without moving the new .DLL to the working directory any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used VS 2010, but I know in 2008, you can specify Post-Build actions in the project properties,  that you could use to copy the output where you need it to go. I would give you more details, but I'm not at work to look at the interface at the moment.